# How to get the attribute from model class and pass to collection view in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Here I am having collection view in which data will be passing from model class here I need to get `special_price` key value pair from `CustomAttribute` and need to pass for collection view in which only some products will have special price and some products won't have special price how to pass the data to collection view I am unable to implement it can anyone help me how to pass data new to swift 3 if anything wrong in declaring or writing model class please correct me ?

```
var listClassModel : ModelClass?
var items = [List]()

func listCategoryDownloadJsonWithURL(listUrl: String) {
        print(listUrl)
        let url = URL(string: listUrl)!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil { print(error!); return }
            do {
                if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:AnyObject] {
                    let objArr = jsonObj["items"] as? [[String:Any]]
                    let objAdd = objArr!.map{List(dict: $0)}
                    self.items.append(contentsOf: objAdd)
                    self.listClassModel = ModelClass(dict: jsonObj as [String : AnyObject])
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        guard let obj = self.listClassModel else { return }
                        let itemsCount = obj.items.count
                        print(itemsCount)
                        for i in 0..<itemsCount {
                            let customAttribute = obj.items[i].customAttribute
                            print(customAttribute.count)
                            for j in 0..<customAttribute.count {
                                if customAttribute[j].attributeCode == "image" {
                                    let baseUrl = "http://192.168.1.11/magento2/pub/media/catalog/product"
                                    self.listCategoryImageArray.append(baseUrl + customAttribute[j].value)
                                }
                                if customAttribute[j].attributeCode == "special_price" {
                                    self.specialPrice.append(customAttribute[j].value)
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        print(self.specialPrice)
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                        self.collectionView.delegate = self
                        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
                        self.collectionView.isHidden = false
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Here is my model class

```
struct ModelClass {
    var items : [List]
    var totalCount : Int
    var searchCriteria : SearchCriteria

    init(dict:[String:AnyObject]) {
        totalCount = dict["total_count"] as! Int
        let searchDict = dict["search_criteria"] as? [String:AnyObject]
        searchCriteria = SearchCriteria(dict: searchDict!)
        let arr = dict["items"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]
        var listArr = [List]()
        for obj in arr! {
            listArr.append(List(dict: obj))
        }
        items = listArr
    }
}

struct List {

    let name : String
    let sku : Any
    let id : Int
    let attributeSetId : Int
    let price : Int
    let status : Int
    let visibility : Int
    let typeId: String
    let createdAt : Any
    let updatedAt : Any
    var customAttribute = [ListAttribute]()

    init(dict : [String:Any]) {
        if let customAttribute = dict["custom_attributes"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            var result = [ListAttribute]()
            for obj in customAttribute {
                result.append(ListAttribute(json: obj)!)
            }
            self.customAttribute = result
        } else {
            self.customAttribute = [ListAttribute]()
        }
        self.name = (dict["name"] as? String)!
        self.sku = dict["sku"]!
        self.id = (dict["id"] as? Int)!
        self.attributeSetId = (dict["attribute_set_id"] as? Int)!
        self.price = (dict["price"] as? Int)!
        self.status = (dict["status"] as? Int)!
        self.visibility = (dict["visibility"] as? Int)!
        self.typeId = (dict["type_id"] as? String)!
        self.createdAt = dict["created_at"]!
        self.updatedAt = dict["updated_at"]!
    }
}
struct ListAttribute {

    let attributeCode : String
    let value : String

    init?(json : [String:AnyObject]) {

        self.attributeCode = (json["attribute_code"])! as! String
        self.value = (json["value"])! as! String

    }
}
```

Here is my image how my Json looks

[image]